# Key 'emp_no' doesn't exist in table 'employees'

Tags: mysql

why does something like this not work?

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM employees FORCE INDEX(emp_no) WHERE emp_no = '77899';
```

where the table looks like this:

```
+------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field      | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| emp_no     | int(11)       | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| birth_date | date          | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| first_name | varchar(14)   | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| last_name  | varchar(16)   | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| gender     | enum('M','F') | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| hire_date  | date          | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
6 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

the error i get is this:

```
ERROR 1176 (42000): Key 'emp_no' doesn't exist in table 'employees'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just because emp_no is the name of the primary key doesn't mean that it's the name of the index.

> Each hint requires the names of indexes, not the names of columns. The name of a PRIMARY KEY is PRIMARY. To see the index names for a table, use SHOW INDEX.
>   http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/index-hints.html

do this instead

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM employees FORCE INDEX(PRIMARY) WHERE emp_no = '77899';
```

Comment: are you sure? this post would suggest otherwise (i think): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1071180/is-the-primary-key-automatically-indexed-in-mysql

Comment: From the [MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimizing-primary-keys.html) (shortened): _The primary key for a table... has an associated index, for fast query performance._

Comment: This was helpful. I still have the issue I think. I do an explain query, and it still claims to be a full table scan.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's complaining (very unhelpfully) because you're doing force index on something that's already an index. Do  `SHOW INDEXES FROM <<tablename>>` to be sure. You shouldn't need the force index clause..

Answer (score 1):

You can add it to the index list first via this query.

`ALTER TABLE employees ADD INDEX emp_no (emp_no);`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).