# Primary key and index on same table

Tags: mysql, indexing, primary-key

I created a table using this query:

`create table tblz (
id int not null auto_increment primary key,
code varchar(20))`

then I added an index:

`alter table tblz add index codeind (code)`

I added 4 records:

`insert into tblz (code) values ('')`

insert into tblz (code) values ('Y')

insert into tblz (code) values ('Z')

insert into tblz (code) values ('')

Then after 
`select * from tblz`:

This is the result:

+----+------+

| id | code |

+----+------+

|  1 |      |

|  4 |      |

|  2 | Y    |

|  3 | Z    |

+----+------+

My question is:
Due to this question [Is the primary key automatically indexed in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1071180/is-the-primary-key-automatically-indexed-in-mysql) the primary key is the clustered index, so why didn't MySQL arrange the records due to the primary key values? or does it arrange the records due to the added index only regardless to the clustered index?

Comment: The primary key is indexed, but unless you specify an order with `ORDER BY` SQL doesn't guarantee which order rows will be returned in. Just because you added them in some sequence doesn't mean they'll be returned in that sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MySQL says](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sorting-rows.html) that row results are returned in "no particular order."  The actual retrieval order depends on the engine, but there is no guarantee of any particular sorting.  You need to use `ORDER BY` (warning -- it can be slow, especially for large result sets) or sort in whatever is retrieving the data.

`PRIMARY KEY` is indexed.  `KEY` and `INDEX` are synonyms, and although there is no `PRIMARY INDEX` syntax, any key that is created is indexed.