# How to Optimize Left Join Query on Large Table

Tags: mysql

I am trying to select a number of items from *table1* that are not in *table2*. *table1* has approximately 3 million rows, and *table2* has approximately 8,000. I already have an index on *table1* for (expire,unreliable,block,deleted,flag,expirationDate). How can I optimize this:

```
SELECT table1.*
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2
ON table1.item_ID = table2.item_ID
WHERE table1.expire = '0'
AND table1.unreliable = '0'
AND table1.block = '0'
AND table1.deleted = '0'
AND table1.flag = '0'
AND table1.expirationDate >= CURDATE() 
AND table2.item_ID IS NULL
GROUP BY item_ID
LIMIT 5000
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an additional index `table2.item_id`. This indexes is important to optimize the `LEFT JOIN`.

Imagine you have two different phonebooks. You are searching for all People starting with "T" (the `WHERE` part) in book A. This is quite fast because you have an index. But for every phone number you have to scan through the full book B trying to find the same phone number there. Using an index (a sorted list of all phone numbers in book B) this is much faster...

Comment: But shouldn't those indexes exists as item_ID is a primary key in both tables?

Comment: You didn't say `item_ID` is you primary key. I'm not sure if mysql automatically creates an index for primary keys. I believe to remember that that's not the case. You can simply check this using `SHOW INDEX`. If it doesn't show such an index, it doesn't exist.

Comment: Ahh, you were right, it wasn't the primary key in the second table. Now it seems to work well. Thanks!

Comment: This explains a lot. And I found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1071180/is-the-primary-key-automatically-indexed-in-mysql which explains that PK always have an index

Comment: MySQL will normally only use one index on a table. So an index on table1.item_id will likely not be of benefit in this query (the index on the columns to check is likely more useful).

Comment: @Kickstart True. I'm used to program oracle databases, and there the optimizer might create a different and more efficient algorithm using a table1.item_id index in some cases.