# Slow performance while fetching data

Tags: php, mysql, query-performance

My website is performing very slow and taking lot of time to load the data.
Its like 2-3 mins to load the data. Can you please suggest me how to make it fast. I am fetching data from multiple table. The database has many entries almost 25000 entries.

Below Is the Code I am currently using.

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered bootstrap-datatable datatable">
<tbody>
  <?php // get all state
     $sql=" SELECT bm.bank_name,b.bank_ifsc,e.emp_id,e.emp_code,
                      e.first_name,e.middle_name,e.last_name,
                      e.active_status as emp_status,
                      e.account_no FROM tblemployee e 
        Left Join tblbank_mst bm  on bm.bank_id=e.fk_bank_id
        Left Join tblbank b  on b.bank_ifsc_id=e.fk_bank_ifsc_id 
        where e.del_status=0
          and e.role_id=4
          and e.is_admin=0 ";
     if($_SESSION["loggedin_role_id"]==2)
     {
     $sql.=" and  e.added_by=".$_SESSION["loggedin_emp_id"];
     }
     $sql.=" order by first_name";

     // echo $sql; exit;

     if(mysql_num_rows($result = mysql_query($sql))>0)
     { 
     while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
     { ?>
  <tr>
     <td><?php echo $row['emp_code'];?> </td>
     <td><?php echo $row['first_name'].' '.$row['middle_name'].' '.$row['last_name'];?> </td>
     <td><?php echo $row['bank_name'];?> </td>
     <td><?php echo $row['account_no'];?> </td>
     <td><?php echo $row['bank_ifsc'];?> </td>
     <td class="center">
        <?php if($row['emp_status']==1){ ?>
        <span class="label label-success">Active</span>
        <?php }else{?>
        <span class="label label-danger">Inactive</span>
        <?php }?>
     </td>
     <td class="center">
        <!--<a class="btn btn-success" href="#">
           <i class="halflings-icon white zoom-in"></i>  
           </a>-->
        <?php if($row['approve_status']==0){ ?>
        <a class="btn btn-info" href="edit_employee.php?emp_id=<?php echo $row['emp_id'];;?>">
        <i class="halflings-icon white edit"></i>  
        </a>
        <a class="btn btn-danger" href="#" onClick="ConfirmDelete(<?php echo $row['emp_id'];?>)">
        <i class="halflings-icon white trash"></i> 
        </a>
        <?php }else{ echo "--"; }?>
     </td>
  </tr>
```

Comment: You should post this in [**Code Review**](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead

Comment: Have you tried running an [explain](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/using-explain.html) on your query to see whether indices are missing?

Comment: Do you using index property for your mysql table fields ?

Comment: Please read this, and pay special attention to the section on query performance.  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question/271056#271056 Please [edit] your question to provide more detail.

Comment: Do _not_ use PHP's `mysql_*` interface.

Comment: Please `echo $sql` so we know what we are working with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your largest table is `tblemployee`, try creating a compound index on the three columns mentioned in your `WHERE` clause, which is:

```
 WHERE e.del_status=0 and e.role_id=4 and e.is_admin=0
```

You can do this with

```
 CREATE INDEX emp_del_role_admin 
           ON tblemployee
              (del_status, role_id, is_admin);
```

Why does this help? Because MySQL's query planner can random-access the index to find the first row of your table matching your `WHERE` statement, then it can read the index sequentially to find the rest of the matching rows.

Of course, if your `WHERE` filter matches many thousands of rows in your table, you will still have a slow page; it takes time to load, transmit, and render a very large page.

Comment: Well, that index may work well for the base query, but not so good for the one where `and  e.added_by` and/or `order by` are tacked on.

Answer (score 0):

**If you are trying to display 25000 (or too many) entries in one time :**

This is slow and that's normal, you should paginate your results  : use some infinite scroll plugin to display the same thing and limiting results for each query *-EDIT : or DataTable pagination options-*.

**If you are not**

First you should have a look at [slow queries](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/slow-query-log.html) , configuration to change in `my.cnf` file.
If your query is slow, you may then optimize your query by adding `INDEX` where you have to. You should use  `EXPLAIN` ([documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/using-explain.html)) to help you doing this.
Be sure you have foreign keys declared as foreign keys (`bm.bank_id` & `e.fk_bank_id` - `b.bank_ifsc_id` & `e.fk_bank_ifsc_id`), that will speed up your query. Adding index on things like `e.role_id` could do it aswell.

Only you can know which index to add in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Do *not* use PHP's `mysql_*` interface; switch to either `mysqli_*` or PDO.

Add two composite indexes:

```
(del_status, role_id, is_admin, first_name)
(del_status, role_id, is_admin, added_by, first_name)
```

The first handles the case where you skip the additional `AND`.

The following pattern may help performance more: Change

```
... bm.bank_name,
...
    Left Join  tblbank_mst bm  ON bm.bank_id=e.fk_bank_id
```

to

```
... ( SELECT bank_name FROM tblbank_mst WHERE bank_id=e.fk_bank_id
    ) AS bank_name,
...
```

Ditto for the other `LEFT JOIN`.

Answer (score -1):

Please see this answer as it might help you:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/35757120/1276062

In short you should check if you have indices on theese columns:

- tblbank_mst.bank_id
- tblemployee.fk_bank_id
- tblbank.bank_ifsc_id
- tblemployee.fk_bank_ifsc_id
- tblemployee.del_status
- tblemployee.role_id
- tblemployee.is_admin
- tblemployee.added_by
- first_name

If the indices won't help you should run EXPLAIN on the query and post the results into the question

Comment: Creating many single-column indexes is generally **harmful** unless those indexes are chosen to accelerate specific queries.

Comment: Furthermore, a single-column index on a "flag" (or other value with low cardinality) will essentially _never_ be used.

Comment: @RickJames Could you please provide a link to some source that supports your statement? I would love to educate myself regarding the low cardinality indices.

Comment: @Kyborek - This forum is littered with examples.  Usually the title is something like "why is mysql not using my index?".  Often, I am one of the answerers, repeating myself.  Others chime in.  Often there is an concrete example.  There are some links.  Also, search for cardinality in https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/table-scan-avoidance.html

Comment: @Kyborek - and I have tried to digest the main tips into http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql .  This gives more tips:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/ricksrots

Comment: @Kyborek -  to experiment yourself, find (or create) a table where some value of an indexed column occurs in more than, say, 30% of the rows.  Then do `EXPLAIN SELECT` to see that the index is not used when it "should".

Comment: @Kyborek - to further experiment, time the `SELECT`, and time the query with `FORCE INDEX(..)`.  It _may_ demonstrate that the index makes it slower.  (There are many factors going on, so the index _may not_ make it slower.)