# How to add column index in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-10

I have tried this in my migration but it does not work as expected.

`$table->string('key')->primary()->index();`

I also tried to use chatgpt but no solutions were correct. So I hit brick wall debugging, I know its something obvious I am missing.

Comment: [A primary key is already an index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1071180/is-the-primary-key-automatically-indexed-in-mysql), so you don't need to add another index.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/migrations

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Welcome to SO, its been answered before but the simples way to index your column is to add this in a new migration, so firstly create a migration like

```
php artisan make:migration add_index_to_key_column_on_table
```

and in that migration

```
Schema::table('table', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->index(['key']);
});
```

Comment: `its been answered before` -> then you should close this question as duplicate

Comment: Thank you this worked, I guess I missed the older answers but thank you for clarifying here!